# How to know UIStackView has finished auto layout if set hidden property of subview

Tags: ios, layout, uistackview

I have a UIStackView and contains subview A and B vertically. If I run

```
[A setHidden:YES];
[B showSubview:selectionBox];
```

The selection box shows in the second line code is not in the right place, the subview A is not hidden immediately, if I delay the second line code 0.1s it will work well.

My question is I don't want to use delay 0.1s solution. Can I wait for `UIStackView` hide A and finish layout then execute line B (By the way I try to add `[stackview layoutIfneeded]` between two line codes, it does not work).

Comment: Could you try putting those two codes are different place? For example setHidden at viewWillAppear, and showSubview in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot because this is in the same function, and viewWillAppear viewDidAppear will be called many times not only for this case

Comment: how about animate the showsubview method?

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{[B showSubview:selectionBox];}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [stackview layoutIfneeded] }];

Comment: I don't think it works, because from the code layout is after show selection box

Comment: The code should be:


[A setHidden:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{[B showSubview:selectionBox];} completion:^(BOOL finished){ [stackview layoutIfneeded] }];

the duration for the animation should be enough time for the delay.
Please try